# Bootstrap table - sort event

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, checkbox, switchery

I have bootstrap table. In first col I have checkbox styled with Switchery plugin.
I'm not able to reinitialize switchery checkbox after table sort event. I found this event:

```
$(function () {
    $('[data-toggle="table"]').bootstrapTable({
        onSort: function (name, order) {
            var elems = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.demo-switch'));
            elems.forEach(function (html) {
                var switchery = new Switchery(html);
            });
        }
    });
});
```

But it looks like the event is called before sort is done... Search event, page event works but sort no. Can anybody help me?

Other question is how can I reinitialize Switchery instances, because everytime I call new ones :)

Comment: use bootstrap data tables it has built in sort  .....

Comment: I use data tables... but this sort event is not working how I need

Comment: please edit and write you complete code ..... html + JavaScript .

Comment: Edited question... So when I sort table I loose checkbox style